# How to write regular expression to filter out string with single occurence of 4 in , separated string array

Tags: javascript, regex

In the below example I need to get the strings which have only 4 and not 44.

```js
var strs = ["3,4,6","4,5,6","1,2,3,4","44,55","55,44","33,44,55"];
var patt = new RegExp(/[,|^\d]*4[,|^\d]*/);
for(i in strs){
    var str = strs[i];
    var res = patt.test(str);
    if(res){
  console.log(str);
    }else{
  console.error(str);
    }
}
```

Comment: use *word boundaries*.

Comment: Should `54` be allowed or are all combinations of digits containing `4` *disallowed*?

Comment: no 54 should not be allowed. Result should be "3,4,6","4,5,6","1,2,3,4"

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/yX9vR2/3 check this.
string like "1,2,3" should be allowed or not? Because it does not contain only 4

Comment: What's wrong with `\b4\b` ?

Comment: Thanks @CasimiretHippolyte its best answer I found.

Comment: Should several single `4`'s be allowed? E.g. `3,4,4` or `4,5,4`. Or does that never occur?

Comment: @ClasG multiple 4's never occur.

Comment: `var patt = /\b4\b/;`

Answer (score 1):

```
^(?!.*(\d4|4\d)).*4.*$
```

- `(?!.*(\d4|4\d))` it ensure that no string should not contain any digit contain 4 and greater than 10.
- `.*4.*` ensure that string contain at least 1 "4".

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/yX9vR2/3)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
^(?!.*(\d4|4\d).*).*$
```

It uses a negative look-ahead to assert that there isn't a combination of `4` followed by a digit, or the other way around.

[See it here at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/nB5xE2/2).

Comment: Thanks man you done it. I was thinking this is something which is not possible by reg exp. Thanks.

Comment: It select 1,2,3 also... :(

Comment: word boundries is shortes and best

Comment: Wasn't exactly evident in the question that `1,2,3` shouldn't be allowed... :S But now that I know it, the title hints it.